# Return specific HTTP Error Code from Grails Command Object validation

Tags: rest, validation, grails

Given a setup of a REST endpoint, which saves a User for example, is it possible to use a Command Object's `validate()` to get specific HTTP error codes, which can just be returned to the Controller for handling the response?

I want to avoid the situation where the Controller action will have to handle lots of `if` blocks, to check for a specific error message, and do a lookup/convert it into a HTTP error code.

For example, I'd like the custom validator to somehow tell the controller to return a 404, if it fails to find a matching user in the database.

The below is not what I have tried. Instead, it is just a proof of concept of the ideal structure I'd like to use for validating REST parameters. Perhaps this is completely wrong, or that there is a better approach. If there is, that would also be welcome.

e.g.:

User.groovy

```
...
class User {
    String username

    static constraints = {
        username unique:true
    }
}
```

UserController.groovy

```
...
class UserController extends RestfulController {
    def update(UserCommand userCmd) {
        /*
         * Not actually working code, but proof of concept of what 
         * I'm trying to achieve
         */
        render status: userCmd.validate()
    }

    class UserCommand {
        Long id
        String username

        static constraints = {
            importFrom User

            /* 
             * I also get that you can't return Error codes via the 
             * custom validator, but also just to illustrate what I'm
             * trying to achieve
             */
            id validator: { 
                User user = User.get(id)
                if(user == null) {
                    return 404
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your example doesn't make a lot of sense. If you're saving a user and it can't be found, that's good, no? And if you're updating a user, you'd probably call an `update()` action in your controller.

That said, while that seems like a good idea, since it won't work, I'd suggest something more like the following:

```
class UserController {

    def edit() {
        withUser { user ->
            [user:user]
        }
    }

    private def withUser(id="id", Closure c) {
        def user = User.get(params[id])
        if(user) {
            c.call user
        } else {
            flash.message = "The user was not found."
            response.sendError 404
        }
    }
}
```

You can adjust that to deal with your command object but I think that gives the general idea of being more `DRY`.

Comment: Could you explain or point me to some docs explaining the `id="id"` parameter in your `withUser ` method? I got no idea what that is I'm afraid.

Comment: It's just a variable that you can override. So if you wanted to look up an object by a different param, you pass that in as the id instead of the default "id".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try returning 404 but then actual error that you parse and do something else with

You are not going to have a huge amount of error codes to play with in the first instance [(that will make proper sense and actually valid)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html)

```
if (userCmd.validate()) {
  def error=userCmd.errors.allErrors.collect{g.message(error : it)}
  render status:404,text: error
  return
}
//otherwise 
 render status:201, text: 'something'
```

you can also do

```
response.status=404
render "Some content"
```